# convert multi file in multi folder with ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, wav, ogg

i want to use **ffmpeg** for convert all file in multi folder
for example
i want to convert all audio on more then 170 folder with ffmpeg at once

```
..\voice\SP_WL6_kismet1_a_LOC_INT\snd_vo_SP_WL_wav
..\voice\SP_WL6_kismet1_a_LOC_INT\ed_vo_SP_WL_wav
....
....
....
```

***This folder also contains files in other formats***

on these folders i have more then 1000, **ogg** file i want to convert all of them to **wav** at once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i use this in cmd and it work for me

```
FOR /R %f IN (*.ogg) DO ffmpeg -i "%f" "%f.wav"
```